# Cant get prefix query to work with elastic search for dotnet

Tags: elasticsearch

I am playing with elastic search and made the following controller action in dotnet.

But the prefix query does not work.

```
    [Entities(Name = "ListStreams")]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(StreamEntity[]), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ListStreams(
          [FromResourceProvider] ResourceProviderRouteData route)
    {
        var clientFactory = new ElasticServiceClientFacotry();
        var client = await clientFactory.CreateClientAsync();


        var documentSearchResult = await client.SearchAsync<StreamEntity>(
                k => k.Index("streams")
                .Routing(route.Routing)
                .Query(q=>q.Prefix(c=> c.Field("id").Value(route.ResourceId)))
                ,
            HttpContext.RequestAborted);
          return Ok(documentSearchResult.Documents);


    }
```

The following data items are in the index

```
[
  {
    "name": "swl2x33p_vjv",
    "id": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/test/providers/EarthML.Streams/streams/swl2x33p_vjv",
    "location": null,
    "type": "EarthML.Streams/streams"
  },
  {
    "name": "gkljqg2j_ic0",
    "id": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/test/providers/EarthML.Streams/streams/gkljqg2j_ic0",
    "location": null,
    "type": "EarthML.Streams/streams"
  }
]
```

and the `route.ResourceId = "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/test/providers/EarthML.Streams"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem being with analyzers, and that I had not created the index myself but relied on the build in auto creation of a index.

As soon as I deleted my index and created it like the following

```
    var descriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor("streams")
                .Mappings(ms => ms
                .Map<StreamEntity>(m => m.AutoMap()
                .Properties(props => props
                    .Keyword(s1 => s1.Name(p => p.Id).Norms(false))
                    .Keyword(k=>k.Name(p=>p.Name).Norms(false))
                    .Keyword(k=>k.Name(p=>p.Type).Norms(false))
                    .Keyword(k => k.Name(p => p.Location).Norms(false))
                 )));
```

then the prefix filter started working.

This also explains why it did not work with default mappings:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings

as the field for the keyword would be `id.keyword` instead now.